# How to add a filename extension to an Next.js url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js

Example : I need to redirect this URL : `https://example.com/data/publications` to this one : `https://example.com/data/publications.json`

I already tried Next.js redirection but I failed to add a string that is not starting with `/`

Example, this doesn't work :

```json
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/data/:slug',
        destination: '/data/:slug.json',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
```

Adding () around .json doesn't help

Comment: What's the use-case for doing so? If you're trying to serve a static JSON file, why don't you move the file to the `public` folder directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a middleware? Middleware is a function that executes when client connects to a specific route.

To use middleware; inside your "pages/data" folder, create "_middleware.js" file and use the code below. This code checks if the url has "json" extension end of it. If it doesn't, then it redirects the client to the url with "json" version.

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export default function myMiddleware(req, e) {
  if (!req.url.endsWith("json")) return new NextResponse.redirect(`${req.url}.json`);
}
```